# Opening Visual Studio solution with different files open

Tags: visual-studio

I have a solution with both a client project and a server project (and a shared common project).

When I open the solution I usually run `mysolution.sln` from the command line. It then opens the solution with the files I had open the last time a closed Visual Studio.

Now, I like to have the solution open twice: one with focus on the server project and one with focus on client project. I think you can guess my question now :)

Is there a way I can save "this configuration of open files" and then have one for server and one for client?

I'm using VS2022 with Resharper, if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `fsutil hardlink create` to create one solution for client and one for the server.